# Using jQuery to open all external links in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to jQuery here.  I've found several web pages that come close to what I'm trying to do, but not quite.  Actually, I think the following is *supposed* to actually work, but it's saying:

```
[@href^="http://"]
```

is not recognized (syntax error).  Any help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[@href^="http://"]').filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
    }).attr('target', '_blank');  
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for the @ symbol. Other than that, you're golden.

```
$("a[href^='http://']")...
```

Comment: Just to expand on this - the @ is deprecated as of jQuery 1.2.6 and 1.3.x.