# Javascript to append iframe to all external URLs

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, append, external

javascript noob trying to figure something out. I saw a script located here:

[Using jQuery to open all external links in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871371/using-jquery-to-open-all-external-links-in-a-new-window)

in which urls on a page are checked to see if they match the current page url. If not, this particular script would open them in a new window. I would like to use the same test on urls but if they are external I would like ?iframe to be appended to each url, a la fancybox syntax. My noob script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[@href^="http://"]').filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
    }).append('?iframe')
});
```

which I believe is incorrect. Any assistance? Thanks

Comment: Well I believe all three of you guys have given me a correct solution to the code, however I can't figure out how to get it to work from the fancybox site, since they use classes in their examples. My apologies, I should've forseen this issue before posting. I guess if the same solution can be applied to attach a class to all external urls then hopefully it will be fancybox compliant? Also, this method takes care of the issues @luke and @felix mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `href` attribute using [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), not `append` new child elements:

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').filter(function() { // no @ before the attribute name
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
}).attr('href', function(i, value) {
    // takes care of URLs with parameters
    return value + (value.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'iframe';
});
```

Note that `hostname` is [only available in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement). So in browsers not supporting HTML 5, the filter would discard every element (*Update: Given that the question you linked to is from 2009, it seems browsers implemented `hostname` but it was not part of any specification*). You can change it to:

```
var hostname = new RegExp("^http://" + location.hostname);

$('a[href^="http://"]').filter(function() {
    return !hostname.test(this.href);
}).attr('href', function(i, value) {
    return value + (value.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'iframe';
});
```

And if you also want to convert links to `https` websites, ditch the attribute selector and change the regular expression:

```
var hostname = new RegExp("^https?://" + location.hostname);

$('a').filter(function() {...
```

---

**Update:**

Specifically for fancybox, according to the [documentation](http://fancybox.net/howto), it should work this way. However, you are right, you could just add the `iframe` class:

```
 $('a').filter(function() {...}).addClass('iframe');
```

Comment: and if I wanted to make the id "iframe", using the first example would i change it to: `.attr('id': 'iframe');`?

Comment: @javy: Yes and no, I just updated my question regarding this ;) You would overwrite the attribute, which means existing classes would be overwritten and you have to set the class as you cannot have more than one element with the same ID (and fancybox uses the class).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of append, which modifies the inner HTML of the element, modify the href attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = $('a[@href^="http://"]').filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
    });

    elements.each(function(index, value) {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?iframe');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `append` method is incorrect. The following code shows how to achieve what you require, plus it takes into account a couple of additional factors that you need to bear in mind, namely:

1) What about links that use https rather than http?
2) What about links that already contains querystring parameters? http://www.blah.com/?something=123 should be changed to http://www.blah.com/?something=123&iframe rather than http://www.blah.com/?something=123?iframe

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href^="http"]').filter(function() {
        return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
    }).each(function() {
        this.href += ((this.href.indexOf('?') >= 0) ? '&' : '?') + 'iframe';
    });
});
```